# to describe someone looks beautiful and young since she was born

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-usage

My friend is forty something but she looks younger than her age. So I asked her "What makes you look so much younger?". She answered jokingly in Chinese "天生麗質" which means her beauty is naturally born. So I'd like to know if the following sentences are correct or comprehensible to native English speakers.

1. I was born this way.
2. I was born beautiful.
3. I was born with a beauty.
4. I am a born beauty.
5. It just comes naturally.
6. I guess it’s a gift from Heaven.
7. It must be genes.
8. I guess it's in my blood.
9. It's gifted.
10. I was born with beauty.

Answer (score 2):

Out of the options you have provided, the ones that are grammatically correct, as well as the ones that are commonly used are:

1. I was born this way. (*The best and probably the most common and natural used one*)
2. I was born beautiful. (*Commonly used*)
3. I am a born beauty. (*Not commonly used, but not wrong*)
4. It just comes naturally. (*Grammatically correct, but generally not used in this context*)
5. I guess it’s a gift from Heaven. (*Fairly common usage*)
6. I guess it's in my blood. (*Commonly used*)

Out of this, the most commonly used ones are:

> - I was born this way
> - I was born beautiful
> - I guess it's in my blood

**Comments for the remaining answers:**

- *I am a born beauty*

  People generally don't say this about themselves, as the speaker may sound very arrogant and self-obsessed.
- *It just comes naturally*

  This is not a wrong answer, but we usually don't associate this with beauty, for things like '*talent*' or '*skills*'

> **Person 1:** Loop at her dance!!
>   **Person 2:** She's always been graceful. It just comes naturally to her.

**Incorrect answers:**

- *I was born with a beauty.*

  You cannot be born with a '*beauty*', but you can be born with a '*beautiful*' feature.

> **Person 1:** That girl is so charming. 
>   **Person 2:** Yes she is. She was born with a beautiful smile.

- *It must be genes.*

  You can make this acceptable if you modify this a bit.

> It must be in my genes.

Comment: *It's in my blood* doesn't sound right to me. It sounds like the person has a viral infection. I dont think people would say that in California.

Comment: @Ringo **[something is in your blood](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/something-is-in-your-blood)**

Comment: @Ringo: Almost any desire can be "in your blood". Dancing,  looking for buried treasure, poetry, whatever.

Comment: But being beautiful is not a desire, right?

Comment: @Ringo - Almost any trait can be in your blood, too. It's an informal and figurative way to say it's genetic.

Answer (score 1):

> I was born this way.
>
> I was born beautiful.

Yes and yes.

> I was born with a beauty.

No, this means you were born with a beautiful person, probably your twin!

> I am a born beauty.

Yes.

> It just comes naturally.

This is something you could say, but this doesn't mean you were born beautiful.

> I guess it’s a gift from Heaven.

Again, this is something people say, but it has nothing to do with being born beautiful.

> It must be genes.

It's a little awkward. Instead, you could say, ***It must be genetic.***

> I guess it's in my blood.

No. This sounds weird. Instead, you could say, ***I guess it runs in the family.***

Comment: I would concur that beauty, though it may be desirable, is not itself a desire, and for that reason cannot be in the blood.